# UTC time is incorrectly displayed as local time

Tags: javascript, python, ruby, date, unix-timestamp

I've found that some dates (at the moment I only found this error with some before-epoch dates) add an hour of difference from UTC.

Local time is GMT-3

First time I see it was in Javascript

```js
> new Date("1969-07-26T03:00:00+00:00")
< Fri Jul 25 1969 23:00:00 GMT-0400 (-03) // why is it -0400?

> new Date("1963-07-26T03:00:00+00:00")
< Fri Jul 26 1963 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (-02)
```

Then I tried in Ruby and the same happened

```rb
irb(main):288:0> Time.parse("1969-07-26T03:00:00+00:00").localtime
=> 1969-07-25 23:00:00 -0400
```

But (maybe I did it wrong) doesn't happen in Python

```py
In [12]: utc = datetime.fromisoformat("1969-07-26T03:00:00+00:00")

In [13]: utc.replace(tzinfo=tz.tzutc())
Out[13]: datetime.datetime(1969, 7, 26, 3, 0, tzinfo=tzutc())

In [14]: utc.astimezone(tz.tzlocal())
Out[14]: datetime.datetime(1969, 7, 26, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzlocal())
```

I haven't been able to find information about it. Anything to read about and how to handle those cases? For example 1963-07-26T03:00:00+00:00 works as expected.

Cheers!

Comment: The difference is probably related to changes in daylight saving time laws.

Comment: I'm not  sure this is the reason for your example, but 1969 was the year that the UK kept DST all year- see e.g https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/uk/london?year=1969#:~:text=Daylight%20Saving%20Time%20in%20Other%20Years%20%20,observed%20all%20year%20%208%20more%20rows%20

Comment: Hi @AHaworth, that make sense, but `new Date("1969-12-26T03:00:00+00:00")` works as expected showing `Fri Dec 26 1969 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (-03)` .

Comment: That's most likely because on Sun, 5 Oct 1969, 00:00 the UTC offset switched from UTC-04:00 to UTC-03:00. Try new Date("1969-10-05T03:00:00+00:00") and new Date("1969-10-06T03:00:00+00:00") to see the change.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `+00:00` to the end of your date string is creating a UTC offset. Since you're specifying zero hours, zero minutes, and zero seconds, it's creating a zero-offset from GMT, or in other-words, setting your timezone to exactly GMT.

For example, I'm in a GMT -5 timezone (US Central). When I create a new JS date using today's date at 6am, I get a subtraction of 5 hours (because GMT -5 is my timezone) :

```
> new Date("2022-06-08T06:00:00+00:00")
// Wed Jun 08 2022 01:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
```

However, if I omit the offset, then it works as expected, and I get the date in my local timezone.

```
> new Date("2022-06-08T06:00:00")
// Wed Jun 08 2022 06:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
```

I can also run your code examples and get the expected result.

```
> new Date("1969-07-26T03:00:00")
// Sat Jul 26 1969 03:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
```

See the section [Date Time String Format](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format) in the ECMAScript specification for more details.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but IMHO you are not reproducing the expected results, `1969-07-26 03:00:00 UTC` should be `1969-07-26 00:00:00 GMT-3`

Comment: FWIW, the JS Date object also seems to be aware of daylight savings time, which may be the source of what you're seeing.  As an example `new Date("2022-07-26T03:00:00+00:00")` gets me GMT -5 (Central Daylight Time), but `new Date("2022-01-26T03:00:00+00:00")` results in GMT - 6 (Central Standard Time).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason is that from Sun, 6 Apr, 1969 00:00 to Sun, 5 Oct 1969, 00:00 the `America/Buenos_Aires` timezone observed a UTC offset of UTC-4h. So I don't think this is an error, rather it is reflecting what the UTC offsets were at this time.

Before 1 Oct, 1963 00:00 (from ~1946), the UTC offset was always 3 hours with no DST.

So the UTC offset in this timezone has varied over time, from UTC-2 to UTC-4, depending on the year and the date. Since Sun, 15 Mar, 2009, the UTC offset has been UTC-3.

I'll add more examples of the varying UTC offsets below, two from your original example and some more to illustrate the varying UTC offsets.

```js
const timeZone = 'America/Buenos_Aires';
const fmt1 = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', { timeStyle: "medium",
  dateStyle: "medium", timeZone: 'UTC'});
const fmt2 = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', { timeStyle: "long",
  dateStyle: "medium", timeZone});

const examples = [
    new Date("1962-07-26T03:00:00+00:00"),
    new Date("1963-07-26T03:00:00+00:00"),
    new Date("1964-07-26T03:00:00+00:00"),
    new Date("1969-07-26T03:00:00+00:00"),
    new Date("2008-10-19T03:00:00+00:00"),
    new Date("2010-07-26T03:00:00+00:00"),
    new Date("2020-07-26T03:00:00+00:00"), 
];

console.log('UTC'.padEnd(25, ' '), 'Local time');  
for(let dt of examples) { 
    console.log(fmt1.format(dt).padEnd(25, ' '), fmt2.format(dt));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Here is a list of the UTC offset changes for the timezone from 1950 onwards, this illustrates the fact that is has changed many times. until 2009 when it has remained at UTC-3.

```js
let { IANAZone, DateTime } = luxon;
const timeZone = new IANAZone('America/Buenos_Aires');

let date = DateTime.fromISO('1950-01-01T03:00:00Z').setZone('UTC');
let endDate = DateTime.now();
let lastOffset = 0;

function formatUTCOffset(offsetMinutes) {
    return (offsetMinutes / 60) + ':' + String(offsetMinutes % 60).padStart(2, '0');
}

console.log('Time'.padEnd(24, ' '), '\t', 'UTC Offset')
while (date < endDate) {
    if (lastOffset !== timeZone.offset(date)) {
        console.log(date.toISO(), '\t', formatUTCOffset(timeZone.offset(date)));
        lastOffset = timeZone.offset(date);
    }
    date = date.plus( { day: 1 } );
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/2.3.1/luxon.min.js" integrity="sha512-Nw0Abk+Ywwk5FzYTxtB70/xJRiCI0S2ORbXI3VBlFpKJ44LM6cW2WxIIolyKEOxOuMI90GIfXdlZRJepu7cczA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time, but you are not answering my question, why I'm getting -4 hours if GMT-3 are -3 hours from UTC.

Comment: Ah yes, apologies, I'll update.

Comment: Yes it was my bad. My assumption was to use a fixed -3 offset while I should have taken offset variation through the time. I've fixed it using pytz in the server side where the dates where having the error, so I can now get a correct UTC time from the localized time, the browser display it correctly because it have the information of the timezones as well, thanks!